# cant understand why jpanel doesnt render

Tags: java, timer, jpanel

im doing a final project for school, but my code is doing something really weird..
if i call a function within the class, the jpanel is displayed, but when i call this function from another class, it doesnt..

**I found a solution..**

calling a method repaint (); after creating 2jpanels.
solve it.

now... how can I close this question, or mark it as solved??
thx alot to everyone who read this.

here is the class.

main class

```
  public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  new GameFrame();}
  }
```

GameFrame class

```
  public class GameFrame extends JFrame {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private static final int baseWidth=192,baseHeight=352;
  private JPanel panel;
  private GamePanel gamePanel;

  public GameFrame() {
    panel = (JPanel) this.getContentPane();
    Dimension d = new Dimension(baseWidth, baseHeight);
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(d));
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.pack();
    this.setTitle("test game..");
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
    init_panelGame();//this will content the real game panel.
}

private void init_panelGame() {
    gamePanel = new GamePanel(this,scale);
    gamePanel.setVisible(true);
    panel.add(gamePanel);
    this.revalidate();}
     }
```

GamePanel class

```
    public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int imgSize = 32;
    public String gameState ="create_row";
private ImagePanel[][] mat_pos = new ImagePanel[6][11];
private Timer tiempo;//changed to a swing timer..

public GamePanel(GameFrame gp,int scale) {
this.setLayout(null);
createRow();//works fine if i call this method from here.
tiempo=new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    gameFlow();
}});
timerStart();
}

public void gameFlow() {//this is the method call by my timer
if (gameState.equals("create_row"))
    {createRow(); //it doesnt render the created row!! this is my problem!!
     gameState = "move_squares";
 return;}
if (gameState.equals("move_squares"))
    {moveSquares();return;}
}

private void moveSquares() {
int runningSquares = 0;
for (int col=0;col<6;col++)
for(int ren=10;ren>=0;ren--)
    {if (mat_pos[col][ren]!=null)
     if (mat_pos[col][ren].state.equals("running"))
     {runningSquares++;
      mat_pos[col][ren+1]=mat_pos[col][ren];
      mat_pos[col][ren]=null;
      if (ren+1==10 || mat_pos[col][ren+2]!=null)
         mat_pos[col][ren+1].state = "stopped";
      int newX,newY;
      newX = imgSize * col;
      newY = imgSize * (ren+1);
      mat_pos[col][ren+1].setBounds(newX,newY, imgSize,imgSize);
     }
}
if (runningSquares==0)
   {gameState="create_row";
   createRow();}
}
public void createRow() {//create 2 panels and add them to this jpanel.
gameState = "move_squares";
int colorRandom1 = (int) (Math.random()*5);
int colorRandom2 = (int) (Math.random()*5);
ImagePanel t1 = new ImagePanel(colorRandom1);
ImagePanel t2 = new ImagePanel(colorRandom2);
int columna = (int) (Math.random()*5);
mat_pos[columna][0] = t1;
mat_pos[columna+1][0] = t2;
t1.setBounds(columna*imgSize,0,32, 32);
t2.setBounds((columna+1)*imgSize,0,32, 32);
this.add(t1);
this.add(t2);
this.revalidate();
}
public void timerStart(){
    tiempo.start();
}
public void timerStop(){
    tiempo.stop();
}
    }
```

//finallly the image panel class wich only creates a simple panel with an img as background

```
    public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public String state = "running";
private Image img;
    private size = 1;

    public ImagePanel(int color) {
    String cad=null;
    this.setVisible(true);
cad = "assets/blue.png";
    this.img = new ImageIcon(cad).getImage();
    crearFondo();
    }

    public void crearFondo() {
    Dimension size = new Dimension(32,32);
    setPreferredSize(size);
    setMinimumSize(size);
    setMaximumSize(size);
    setSize(size);
    setLayout(null);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(img, 0,0, null);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you generally need to revalidate after adding things to a container if it is already attached to the component hierarchy and visible.

Try calling this.revalidate() after the this.add() call in your createRow method.

Secondly, you seem to be using a java.util.Timer. This will not call you on the EDT. Use a javax.swing.Timer instead or make sure that createRow switches back to the EDT. This can be done with SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {...}). You should fix this no matter if my first suggestion works!

If that does not work, please provide a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/), ideally one that I can copy-paste and try on my end.

Comment: thanks a lot, I put a revalidate() method but I still have the same problem..
is there any other way to put a jpanel into another jpanel so it will force render?
am I talking crazy?

Comment: The code isn't compiling. Fixed the following for it to compile:
A) "scale" set to 1 (not ever used though).
B) Removed a break-statement in constructor of ImagePanel because that shouldn't compile.
C) Instead of "cad" in constructor of ImagePanel I had to find my own resource and used something similar to

**this.img = new ImageIcon(getClass()
.getResource("/random-32x32-image-found-on-web.jpg")).getImage();**

With these changes, I can see 2 of the image side by side moving down each second. Works for me.

Comment: thx. but still is happening a weird thing (at least for me), that i cant understand, becouse, u dont see the jpanels at row 0. unless u add a repaint() methot, but u can see the jpanel in row 1 and above..